# Input string was not in a correct format - Parsing?

Tags: c#, string, parsing, tostring, tryparse

I have a page with multiple TextBoxes and ComboBoxes that takes input from user.

Then, I am passing these values forward to save them into my database.

I am encountering error when clicked "Save":

```
System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
```

Here is the code that returns error:

```
Db_Helper.Insert(new Product(DescriptionBox.Text, int.Parse(QuantityBox.Text), UnitCombo.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                int.Parse(RecurrenceTimesCombo.SelectedItem.ToString()), RecurrenceEveryCombo.SelectedItem.ToString(), InterchangeCombo1.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                InterchangeCombo2.SelectedItem.ToString(), InterchangeCombo3.SelectedItem.ToString(), PickCatCombo.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                PickDietCombo.SelectedItem.ToString()));
```

Here is the bigger picture:

```
private async void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        DatabaseHelperClass Db_Helper = new DatabaseHelperClass();//Creating object for DatabaseHelperClass.cs from ViewModel/DatabaseHelperClass.cs    
        if (DescriptionBox.Text != "" & QuantityBox.Text != "" & UnitCombo.SelectedItem.ToString() != "" &
            RecurrenceTimesCombo.SelectedItem.ToString() != "" & RecurrenceEveryCombo.SelectedItem.ToString() != "" &
            PickCatCombo.SelectedItem.ToString() != "" & PickDietCombo.SelectedItem.ToString() != "")
        {
            Db_Helper.Insert(new Product(DescriptionBox.Text, int.Parse(QuantityBox.Text), UnitCombo.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                int.Parse(RecurrenceTimesCombo.SelectedItem.ToString()), RecurrenceEveryCombo.SelectedItem.ToString(), InterchangeCombo1.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                InterchangeCombo2.SelectedItem.ToString(), InterchangeCombo3.SelectedItem.ToString(), PickCatCombo.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                PickDietCombo.SelectedItem.ToString()));
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(ProductsPage));//after adding product redirect to products listbox page    
        }
        else
        {
            MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog("Please provide all data needed.");//Text should not be empty    
            await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

And here is my Products class:

```
public class Product
{

    [SQLite.Net.Attributes.PrimaryKey, SQLite.Net.Attributes.AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProductQuantity { get; set; }
    public string ProductQuantityUnit { get; set; }
    public int RecurrenceTimes { get; set; }
    public string RecurrenceEvery { get; set; }
    public string Interchangeable1 { get; set; }
    public string Interchangeable2 { get; set; }
    public string Interchangeable3 { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string DietID { get; set; }

    public Product(string name, int prodQuantity, string productQuantityUnit, 
        int recTimes, string recEvery, string interchange1, string interchange2, 
        string interchange3, string cat, string dietId)
    {
        CreationDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        Name = name;
        ProductQuantity = prodQuantity;
        ProductQuantityUnit = productQuantityUnit;
        RecurrenceTimes = recTimes;
        RecurrenceEvery = recEvery;
        Interchangeable1 = interchange1;
        Interchangeable2 = interchange2;
        Interchangeable3 = interchange3;
        Category = cat;
        DietID = dietId;


    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Error does not show up on build. It only shows up when application is already running upon Button Click.

Comment: please don't downvote. I am a beginner in c# and I learn on my own.

Comment: please edit the question with more data and the whole code, to provide better perspective and for people to understand the problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, looks like one of the values you are passing to `int.Parse` is not an integer after all. But which value causes the problem? (It probably is `RecurrenceTimesCombo.SelectedItem.ToString()` which is the text of the item, not its numeric value!?)

To make debugging easier, and also to provide helpful feedback to the user, I would recommend doing the parsing in a separate step, and throwing meaningful exceptions if the parsing fails. You can use [`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of `Parse`, which returns `false` if the value can not be parsed.

Also, if you want to make sure that the input is not empty, use `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(QuantityBox.Text)` instead of `QuantityBox.Text != ""`, which does not test for `null` or a string with only whitespace `"    "`.

```
int quantityNumber;
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(QuantityBox.Text) 
    || !int.TryParse(QuantityBox.Text, out quantityNumber)) {
    throw new ArgumentException(
        $"Expected an integer in QuantityBox, but actual value was '{QuantityBox.Text}'.", 
        nameof(QuantityBox.Text)
    );
}
// if we reach this line, quanityNumber has a valid value assigned
```